# How to couple django oauth2 with javascript (reactjs) frontend correctly?

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, oauth-2.0

I've got a big problem to correctly implement (couple) **oauth2** within Django project with Javascript (**reactjs**) **frontend**.
As a **backend** we are using **Django** server - this server offers some APIs to store or retrieve data from SQL database.

I am following this guide: [Django OAuth Toolkit Documentation](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and using password based grant type (there are three others at disposal).

What is working for me is that I can access server's API calls via command line using **curl**. That is, I know how to acquire **token** using URL like example.com/o/token and then I can call some of my APIs with granted token within header as "Authorization: Bearer acquired_token".

I am new to **OAuth** within little knowledge on this topic so far.

**For information:**
all the stuff is running within **Docker** container. **Reactjs** is build using webpack. Within first request (clean browser cache - no javascript/**reactjs** available) django server is contacted and it servers index.html page with all the javascript stuff. Then **Reactjs** is present in browser and runs the **Reactjs** frontend which makes calls to APIs to get data from database and show them within some tables, etc.

My **problem** and **question** is what needs to be done on **frontend** side (javascript - reactjs) and in what order.

Yet I am also not sure, what to use actually within **OAuth** - password or authorization token and also what yet needs to be done on **backend** side.

**Last note:** I know there are lot of resources on this topic on the world wide web. However, somehow I could not find clear procedure how to deploy it.

Any good piece of advice on this perhaps with pointers to some resources is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Hi You can try [API Automation]( http://www.apimonk.com) to automate your web API's we also have authentication API ready to use.